# VBA Macro to run when Modified workbook Date/Time is greater than another

Tags: excel, vba

I have a master report that is exported lets call that master.csv, I also have a report that was created to pull all relevant information from the .csv, lets call that relevant.xlsx.

I have a Master macro that currently is opened when it opens it updates all records on relevant.xlsx then auto closes.

Is there a condition I can write in VBA that checks if master.csv's modified date is greater than relevant.xlsx's modified day then run my master macro?

I can do and google enough to find answers to most of my issues when it comes to coding however this is one thing that my google powers could not confirm there is an answer to.

If you're wondering why in need this is because currently Outlook is told when to run mastermacro by a report confirmation email and we would like to get away from that incase exchange goes down for some reason.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where is the "Master macro"? Is it in the relevant.xlsx file, in Outlook, or in some other Excel file?

Comment: It's actually in a separate file it's own xlsm book to limit access to it so it's not modified or broken.

Comment: If you are asking if it is possible to have your macro check the modified dates of the files and optionally do the update, the answer is yes.  If you are asking if it is possible to *trigger* your macro if the csv file is modified, the answer is... maybe, if you use vbscript or taskscheduler or something external to VBA.  If it's the former, let me know and I'll post an answer for you!

Comment: Well either really, the only limitation is taskscheduler is out of the question per the IT red tape gods unfortunately because that was the initial plan.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using [FileDateTime](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/filedatetime.php)

At the very beginning of your Master macro, you can use FileDateTime to check the modified dates of the two files and make the decision to run the update or not.

Comment: I think this will work, I may be able to get to the conditions coding by the end of the week. But I suppose as long as I can pass the dates and check for my condition it should work. I will post back at the latest next week regarding if this is solved or not.

Comment: Yes this will work, I've only had a little time to play with it so the tweaking will have to begin. It may be a resource hog though so I may have to abandon the notion of having this macro ran only. The email trigger may have to suffice for the long run, it's just a little cumbersome with too many links in the chain. Thanks!